# localizerouter not changing language after publish

Tags: angular

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router) and I have this code in component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {LocalizeRouterService} from 'localize-router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(private localize: LocalizeRouterService) {}

  changeLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.localize.changeLanguage(lang);
  }
}
```

and in html

```
<button (click)="changeLanguage('en')">EN</button>
<button (click)="changeLanguage('de')">DE</button>
```

This works well in localhost but as soon I publish it using `ng build --prod` and host in IIS it logs this error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The app is trying to load the `JSON` config file from the localize router. My guess is you forgot to add it to your assets array inside `angular-cli.json`. Because your webserver is set to serve any 404 requests with your `index.html` file, the app is trying to parse an `html` file as json, which will result in the typical error:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Where the token `<` is the beginning of the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag.

In short, edit your `angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "apps": [
    {
      ...
      "assets": [
        ...,
        "path/to/localize-router/config.json"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

It could also be that you forgot to add your dictionary `json` files to the assets folder. But for that, the same recipe applies as described above

Comment: can't find any config.json inside node_modules/localize-router folder http://i.imgur.com/BoUqWTT.png

Comment: @gsiradze it's a configuration file you made yourself. [read here](https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router#json-config-file), It could also be that it's a dictionary file you forgot to add to your assets (ive updated my answer)

Comment: Ok I did that http://i.imgur.com/VZOBxPN.png but I'm getting an error on build prod: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\loca`

Comment: should I add `ILocalizeRouteConfig` interface in my code?

Comment: that's odd, it's already inside your assets folder, so it should work. No need to add it to your config then

Comment: check your chrome console, to see what json file it's trying to load, and from where. Then check your webserver to see what the location is of that file